# Questions on how to do a basic javascript / node.js HTTP post? Using the request library

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, request

**Followup #2**: I think this is 99% "my bad" for not properly using a callback (that calls a callback that calls a callback...) idiom of node.js.  When I refactor it properly everything seems to work, even in IntelliJ.  I even figured out a way to arrange the callback functions that seems vaguely sane to a java programmer.  Not sure why it worked on the command line but probably something with how node.js handles the threading/asynch stuff.

Not sure if I should delete this entire question or not.

original question follows:

I'm a veteran Java programmer with next to zero experience in Javascript, node.js, or request.  I want to do a basic HTTP GET (and eventually a POST).  Mikeal's request framework (https://github.com/mikeal/request) looks reasonable.  But I can't figure out how to get the response into a variable so it can then be parsed.  His examples all have it going to the console.

My code is

```
var Request = require('request');
var ggg;
Request.get('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
        ggg = body;

});
```

I'm running it in the IntelliJ Webstorm7 debugger.  I set a breakpoint within the callback, (at the ggg = body line) which never gets triggered.  And, for the record, the console isn't logging anything either.  At a breakpoint after this code, ggg is listed as "undefined".

Not sure if this is my misunderstanding, a weirdness in IntelliJ, or that the request library just doesn't work.

**Followup**: I think something in my intellij is messed up.  When I run this code from the command line via    node nameoffile.js is seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually first of all do

```
npm list
```

and check if you have `request` installed...else install using

```
npm install request
```

Then you have a simple bug in your code.Your are missing a semicolon after console.log

```
console.log(body);
```

Comment: Thanks for the `npm list` hint!  This got me slightly started in the right direction.  See **Followup #2** section in edited question for the full answer.